# You will never be getting it back vs. you will never be able to get it back

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Let's say you left your watch at your friend's house in England, and then you came back home in Ireland. 2 days after, your friend phoned you to tell you that you forgot your watch, while laughing at you at the same time, like this:

> Friend:hey dude you forgot your watch here at my house! Bwahahaha!
>
> You: oh my!
>
> Friend: haha you **will never be getting it back**

Vs.

> Friend: haha you **will never be able to get it back**

What is the *difference* between these two in context?

Comment: why not _you'll never get it back_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general usage, there is no difference. But there is a difference in meaning upon analysis.

> You will never be getting it back.

This means that it's not going to happen. Perhaps your friend is going to wear it himself and not let you take it from him.

In other words, "I'm not going to give it back to you."

> You will never be able to get it back.

This means that it won't be *possible* to get it back. Perhaps your friend smashed it with a hammer and threw the pieces in a river.

In other words, "I'm going to make it so you can't get it back."